# Removing a library included in a shared library

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, symbols

**Background of the question:**
I've a library, say *mylib.so* that includes an old *libpng*.
Now (due to recent Google Play policies) I've to use a newer *libpng*; but this can be difficult, as the library was compiled long ago, and it can be very long to gather again all the libraries needed, with the old version... and so on.

**Question:**

Is it possible to "remove" specific entries from the file *mylib.so*, so that I can then link both *mylib.so* and the new *libpng.so* from my apps, and everything will run nicely (obviously, if the libpng is backward compatible with the one previously linked *inside* mylib.so)?

I don't know the internals of shared libraries, but I hope that somehow the linker can be able to do this without to recompile the whole *mylib.so*...
Am I too optimistic?

**Extra question** (not the main one, but I'd like to understand it): if *mylib.so* includes an old *libpng* and I link to both *mylib.so* and a new *libpng*... what happens? I mean, the linker is allowing me to link 2 libraries probably with a similar names of exported symbols... but it's a bit confusing...

Comment: Is the dependency versioned or unversioned? `readelf` can tell you that. If it's unversioned, you shouldn't have to do anything, it should just work.

Comment: Google Play policies seems quite strict, they don't want the old _libpng_ being present in your app.... for this reason I was trying a way to remove, corrupt :-) or do something to overcome this problem without having to recompile _mylib.so_

Comment: 1) This is apparently not about one of the different languages C or C++. 2) Looks like an XY problem. You shoudl update your program/lib to use the new libpng; even **iff** the interface did not change, semantics can. Maybe you can write a wrapper lib. 3) Messing with libpng is a very bad idea, as that is likely to break other code in the system. 4) Not clear what you really want. What do you mean with "specific entries"?

Comment: Hi @Olaf... well, the point is, having a library already compiled, can I remove something from it?

Comment: (ops, sent incomplete comment by mistake) The point is: if I remove the libpng from inside _mylib.so_ maybe I can then include it from outside, as @KerrekSB highlighted...

Comment: The library is an old OpenCV 2.3.1, nothing special, but this specific problem raised a nice question: **in general** can I remove specific entries, symbols, from an already made shared library?

Comment: "if I remove the libpng from inside mylib.so maybe I can then include it from outside" - so do you not use it as **shared** library, but static library? I don't see the problem then. Nevertheless, the question cannot be answered as asked. I have some feeling you don't know yourself what your actual problem is. You first should clearly identify this before you start searching for a solution.

Comment: @Olaf ..... don't understand what you don't understand, but please help me understand it... :-) 
I've a library mylib.so, that I think to be a shared library (not a mylib.a), where is included also an old _libpng_. Google Play complained about this to be a problematic libpng and I've to replace it with a new one.

My idea is: can I remove the sections of this _mylib.so_ that refers to libpng, so that the rest I can then link my app with both mylib.so and libpng.so ?
If the question is wrong, can you give me ideas of why it is wrong? Thanx!!!

Comment: If you're replacing libpng-1.2.x with libpng-1.6.x you need to recompile, but if you're replacing libpng-1.2.x with libpng-1.2.y (a newer libpng12) or libpng-1.6.x with a newer libpng-1.6.y (a newer libpng16) then you should only need to relink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to "remove" specific entries from the file mylib.so,

No.

Most UNIX systems (with the exception of AIX) consider `.so` as the *final* link product, and no further modification is possible.

> if mylib.so includes an old libpng and I link to both mylib.so and a new libpng... what happens?

Your program exhibits undefined behavior by violating the one definition rule. Usually it will simply crash, but anything else is possible too. It could, for example, silently corrupt your stack and cause a crash only once an hour, or once a day. Such bugs are the hardest to find. Just *don't* do it.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying all night long, with readelf and objdump, but at the end I understood that it's not too obvious... at least not with simply available commands.

If there is not somebody giving a solution, this seems a correct solution: there is not a solution... :-)